# ssh - What happens if there are multiple computers with the exact same name on a local network?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking

In my local network, I can connect my colleague's computer with using:

`ssh friend@friend-CASPER-NIRVANA.local`

Then if I type their password correctly, I can get in.

This made me think what would happen if there is another computer that has the exact same name with also same password in our network. What would happen then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather unrelated to ssh but more how hostnames are resolved. Most likely with [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) in your local network situation.

Assuming you have two computers with the same name (which is unlikely; see below) ssh will warn you because the servers public key won't match. The ssh server sends you a public key to identify itself. On first connect ssh will ask you if this is actually the server you want connect to and then will store the public key in a file known as [known_hosts](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-known-hosts-file-for-ssh).

From that moment your ssh client knows what public key "friend-CASPER-NIRVANA.local" has. If you later connect to another computer under the same name that computer will send you a different public key and ssh will warn you about a potential [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and refuse to connect.

For the name resolution: there will be no duplicated names if all devices in the network adhere to [the standard](https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/47/slides/zeroconf-dns-00mar/tsld009.htm). Then they will choose a different name if they detect a conflict.

If you have a malicious client in your network, most likely the first one announcing its name will win but you should not count on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this brief and crystal clear explanation. I'm kinda new to these things, trying to learn as fast as possible :)